# How to use query parameter "fields" in POST request?

Tags: vimeo-api

I want to set video chupters in batch, but don't understand how to use quesry parameter fields to set it. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uh8Ow.png),

```
[
          {
            timecode: 15,
            title: 'Chapter title 3',
          },
          {
            timecode: 25,
            title: 'Chapter title 4',
          },
         ]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no bulk endpoint for chapters right now, you must make a separate request for each chapter, i.e.

{
timecode: 1234,
title "Chapter 1"
}